# How widely known is it that Korra has lost her connection to her past lives?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

At the end of Season 2, Korra loses her ability to connect with her Avatar Spirit's past lives. Since this vast repository of innate knowledge encompassing several centuries of bending, diplomacy, and military strategy is lost to Korra, this is actually a pretty major setback. It is pretty obvious that everyone in her inner circle is aware of this. How widely known is it that Korra has lost access to this repository of knowledge?